# Memory Cache .Net Core Not Persisting Values

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, .net-core, memorycache

I have a .NET Core 2.1 application. In `Startup.cs` configuration method, I use:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
...

services.AddMemoryCache();
```

Then in my controller:

```
public class DropDownListController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    private const string ProvidersCacheKey = "providers";
    private const string AgenciesCacheKey = "agencies";

    public DropDownListController(ApplicationDbContext context, IMemoryCache memoryCache )
    {
        _context = context;
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }
}
```

and in the controller also, the method to get the dropdownlist:

```
public JsonResult GetProvider()
{
    IEnumerable<DropDownListCode.NameValueStr> providerlist;

    if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue(ProvidersCacheKey, out providerlist))
    {
        return Json(providerlist);
    }
    else
    {
        MemoryCacheEntryOptions cacheExpirationOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions();
        cacheExpirationOptions.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
        cacheExpirationOptions.Priority = CacheItemPriority.Normal;

        DropDownListCode um = new DropDownListCode(_context);
        var result = um.GetProviderList();

        _memoryCache.Set(ProvidersCacheKey, result);

        return Json(result);
    }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint on the line:

```
return Json(providerlist);
```

I see the `ProvidersCacheKey` is in the `_memoryCache`, but it has no value.

What happened to the data?

When I do a Quick Watch on `_memoryCache`, I can see the `DbContext` object was destroyed. But how can that be, the code works fine but the cache object does not have the data I saved to it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first time this hits, it should be falling into the "else" condition, what is the value of "result" after the call to GetProviderList? Can you include the code for GetProviderList().  One quick thing to try, if GetProviderList is returning IQueryable or IEnumerable you might try: `var result = up.GetProviderList().ToList();` just to ensure the entities are loaded. IMO though you should avoid caching entities and use POCO data instead. Later calls with different DbContexts will not have these cached entities associated to them if you try using them as references.

Comment: Excellent: adding ".ToList()" solved the problem. I will make a new entry to mark the question solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method to get providers is:

```
public IEnumerable<NameValueStr> GetProviderList()
    {
        var providerlist = (from a in _context.AgencyProvider
                            where a.Provider == a.AgencyId
                            select new NameValueStr
                            {
                                id = a.Provider,
                                name = a.Name
                            });

        return providerlist.Distinct();
    }
```

Adding "ToList()" in the calling method worked:

```
MemoryCacheEntryOptions cacheExpirationOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions();
            cacheExpirationOptions.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
            cacheExpirationOptions.Priority = CacheItemPriority.Normal;
            DropDownListCode um = new DropDownListCode(_context);
            var result = um.GetProviderList().ToList();
            _memoryCache.Set(ProvidersCacheKey, result);
            return Json(result);
```

All credit goes to Steve Py… Thank you sir!